# Issues with thread and dynamic list in python

Tags: python, multithreading, dynamic-list

I will try to be clear, hoping everyobdy will understand even if it will not be easy for me. 
I'm a beginner in coding in python so every help will be nice !
I've got those librairies import : requests and threading.
I'm trying to send in parrallel several urls to reduce the sending time of data. I used a dynamic list to stack all urls and then used requests.post to send them.

```
l=[]
        if ALARM&1:
            alarmType="Break Alarm"
            AlarmNumber = 1
            sendAlarm(alarmType, AlarmNumber)
            print alarmType
        else:
            s = "https://..." #the url works 
            l.append(threading.Thread(target=requests.post, args=(s)))
        if ALARM&2:
            alarmType=0
        if ALARM&4:
            alarmType="Limit Switch"
            AlarmNumber = 2
            sendAlarm(alarmType, AlarmNumber)
            print alarmType
        else:
            s="https://..." 
            l.append(threading.Thread(target=requests.post, args=(s)))

        for t in l:
            t.start()
        for t in l:
            t.join()
```

The error that I got is :

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: post() takes at most 3 arguments (110 given)
```

And same thing for Thread-2, I asked around me but we can't find a solution. If someone have an idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread), args should be a tuple.

> class `threading.Thread`(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={})
>
> args is the argument tuple for the target invocation. Defaults to ().

You need to pass `args` a tuple with the url as the first (and only) element:

```
l.append(threading.Thread(target=requests.post, args=(s,)))
```

The seemingly useless comma here is what makes Pyhton interpret (s,) as a set and not just a string surrounded by unneeded parenthesis.

Failing to do this, you're basically passing a string, and `Thread` iterates on it, passing `post` each letter as a separate argument, hence the error message:

> ```
> TypeError: post() takes at most 3 arguments (110 given)
> ```

A string being interpreted as an iterator is a common pitfall. A function/method expects a list/set, and when provided a string like `"https://..."`, it treats it like `['"', 'h', 't', 't', 'p', 's', ':', '/', '/',...]`.

The root cause of the issue is anecdotal, somehow. What's interesting, here, is that although I knew about nothing of `Thread` when reading the question, the error message (`TypeError: post() takes at most 3 arguments (110 given)`) pointed me to the right direction right away.

Comment: Using `args=(s,)` is sufficient to define the tuple, I don't think you need the extra parentheses around it, do you? Also, it's worth clarifying that a single-element tuple requires a comma to make it a tuple, as that is the root cause of OP's problem, I think.

Comment: @SiHa: good point. It is likely that OP intended to use a set but missed that specific point.

Comment: Thanks Jérôme its working ! I've passed hours on it ! I should be more cautious and looking more at the docs.. Thanks again !

Comment: Great. Welcome to SO. You can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) since it solves your problem. You may also upvote it.